# Python JSON add Key-Value pair

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm trying to add key value pairs into the existing JSON file. I am able to concatenate to the parent label, How to add value to the child items?

**JSON file:**

```
{
  "students": [
    {
      "name": "Hendrick"
    },
    {
      "name": "Mikey"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Code:**

```
import json

with open("input.json") as json_file:
    json_decoded = json.load(json_file)

json_decoded['country'] = 'UK'

with open("output.json", 'w') as json_file:
    for d in json_decoded[students]:
        json.dump(json_decoded, json_file)
```

**Expected Results:**

```
{
  "students": [
    {
      "name": "Hendrick",
      "country": "UK"
    },
    {
      "name": "Mikey",
      "country": "UK"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the following in order to manipulate the `dict` the way you want:

```
for s in json_decoded['students']:
    s['country'] = 'UK'
```

`json_decoded['students']` is a `list` of dictionaries that you can simply iterate and update in a loop. Now you can dump the entire object:

```
with open("output.json", 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(json_decoded, json_file)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import json

with open("input.json", 'r') as json_file:
    json_decoded = json.load(json_file)

    for element in json_decoded['students']:
        element['country'] = 'UK'

    with open("output.json", 'w') as json_out_file:
        json.dump(json_decoded, json_out_file)
```

1. opened a json file i.e. input.json
2. iterated through each of its element
3. add a key named "country" and dynamic value "UK", to each element
4. opened a new json file with the modified JSON.

#### Edit:

Moved writing to output file inside to first `with` segment. Issue with earlier implemenation is that `json_decoded` will not be instantiated if opening of `input.json` fails. And hence, writing to output will raise an exception - `NameError: name 'json_decoded' is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

This gives `[None, None]` but update the dict:

```
a = {'students': [{'name': 'Hendrick'}, {'name': 'Mikey'}]}
[i.update({'country':'UK'}) for i in a['students']]
print(a)
```