# Update & Add (keys, values) pairs of dictionary in JSON File using python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am trying to `update`,`add` key,value pairs of dict into JSON File.

JSON File- hi.json

```
{
    "site_post": {
            "site_name":"test site",
            "location" : "test location",
            "latitude": "123.23",
            "longitude": "456.23"
                },  
    "plant_post": {
         "plant_name" : "plant test",
          "site_id" : "",
          "plant_id": ""
          }
}
```

```
import json
with open('hi.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

dct = {"site_id":"123","plant_id":"456"}
```

Expected Output- hi.json

```
{
    "site_post": {
            "site_name":"test site",
            "location" : "test location",
            "latitude": "123.23",
            "longitude": "456.23",
            "site_id" : "123"
                },  
    "plant_post": {
         "plant_name" : "plant test",
          "site_id" : "123",
          "plant_id": "456"
          }
}
```

I checked using below posts, but didn't find expected ans.
Ref link-

[Update Key Value In Python In JSON File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55943593/update-key-value-in-python-in-json-file)

[Python JSON add Key-Value pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53043241/python-json-add-key-value-pair)

Comment: You don't update the json. You read the json into a dict, update the dict, then use that to completely rewrite the json file. Both questions you linked have the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update `data` dictionary and write back to the file

```
dct = {"site_id": "123", "plant_id": "456"}

with open('hi.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    data['site_post']['site_id'] = dct['site_id']
    data['plant_post']['site_id'] = dct['site_id']
    data['plant_post']['plant_id'] = dct['plant_id']

with open('hi.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
```

`hi.json`:

```
{
    "site_post": {
        "site_name": "test site",
        "location": "test location",
        "latitude": "123.23",
        "longitude": "456.23",
        "site_id": "123"
    },
    "plant_post": {
        "plant_name": "plant test",
        "site_id": "123",
        "plant_id": "456"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would split dct into two variables or use get to receive what you need, use .update() to update your dict and then write it to hi.json using json.dump

```
import json
with open('hi.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

update_site_post = {"site_id": "123"}
update_plant_post = {"plant_id": "456"}
data.get("site_post").update(update_site_post)
data.get("plant_post").update(update_plant_post)

with open('hi.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```